# How do I get the submitted value for a field?

Tags: forms

I have a custom submit handler:

```
function submituserform(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $email = $form_state->getValue('field_email');
  drupal_set_message('Thank you for for submitting your application. You will receive a confirmation at ' . $email . ');

  $redirect_path = "/confirmation";
  $url = url::fromUserInput($redirect_path);
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

}

I get `Array` as value for the email. How do I get the email from field_email?

Comment: [PHP Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp), get good. Install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and `dpm($form_state->getValue('field_email'));` to see the structure of the array.

Comment: @NoSssweat Thank you. I added this: $value = $form_state->getValue('field_email');  $email = $value[0]['value'];

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in following way:

```
function submituserform(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $element = $form['field_email'];
  $email = $form_state->getValue($element['#parents']);
```